# OID for the last added feature

Tags: arcmap, c#, features

How can i get the Object ID for the last feature created ?
i use `m_editEvents_OnSketchFinished()` event to run some code, but i can't get the OID
of the most recent added feature.

Comment: Dude, please give us more context for your questions, ArcGIS Server? Arcobjects? ArcMap? Addin? Windows? etc.etc. OID - of what? geodatabase? shapefile? SDE?

Comment: i have a polyline featureClass.mdb , when i draw a new feature (line) in ArcMap i want to get the OID for this feature (line). how do i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how to get the OID

```
   void _EditEvents_OnCreateFeature(IObject obj) {

                IFeature featureT;           
                if (obj is IFeature) {
                    featureT = (IFeature)obj;
                    int oid = featureT.OID;
          }
```

Comment: you don't need to QI IFeature--IObject has OID/HasOID properties: http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/OID_Property/0025000007wt000000/